# From a numpy array of coordinates[x,y], remove other coordinates with a same x-value to keep the coordinate which has the maximum for y

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, coordinates

Suppose I have a Numpy array of  a bunch of coordinates [x, y].
I want to filter this array. 
For all coordinates in the array with a same x-value, I want to keep only one coordinate: 
The coordinate with the maximum for the y.
What is the most efficient or Pythonic way to do this.
I will explain with an example below.

```
coord_arr= array([[10,5], [11,6], [12,6], [10,1], [11,0],[12,2]])
```

[10, 5] and [10,1] have the same x-value: x=10
maximum for y-values: 
max(5,1) = 5
So I only keep coordinate [10,5]

Same procedure for x=11 and x=12
So I finally end up with:

```
filtered_coord_arr= array([[10,5],[11,6],[12,6]])
```

I have a solution by converting to a list and using list comprehension (see below).
 But I am looking for a more efficient and elegant solution. 
(The actual arrays are much larger than in this example.)
My solution:

```
coord_list = coord_arr.tolist()
x_set = set([coord[0] for coord in coord_list])
coord_max_y_list= []
for x in x_set:
    compare_list=[coord for coord in coord_list if coord[0]==x]
    coord_max = compare_list[compare_list.index(max([coord[1] for coord[1] in compare_list]))]
    coord_max_y_list.append(coord_max)
filtered_coord_arr= np.array(coord_max_y_list)
```

Comment: What does it mean that they are equal for the coordinate values **`x`**, and the **maximum** values of **`y`**?, `array([[10,5],[11,6],[12,6]])` are not equal *x-values* and also, which would be the condition of obtaining an array of 3 values being the first array of 8?

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your array in small you can just do it one line:

```
np.array([[x, max(coord[coord[:,0] == x][:,1])] for x in  set(coord[:,0])])
```

however that is not correct complexity, if array is big and you care about correct complexity , do like this:

```
d  = {}
for x, y in coord:
    d[x] = max(d.get(x, float('-Inf')), y)
np.array([[x, y] for x,y in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below answer :

**Solution :**

```
coord_arr= np.array([[10, 5], [11, 6], [12, 6], [13,7], [10,1], [10,7],[12,2], [13,0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(coord_arr,columns=['a','b'])
df = df.groupby(['a']).agg({'b': ['max']})
df.columns = ['b']
df = df.reset_index()
filtered_coord_arr = np.array(df)

filtered_coord_arr
```

**Output :**

```
array([[10,  7],
       [11,  6],
       [12,  6],
       [13,  7]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks more elegant indeed. But it takes around x10 more time than my own solution.